# C++: Can I define vector within another vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector

In C/C++ pure array, you can define an array within another array, for example:

```
int a[5];
int *p = &a[1];
```

So that if you change `p[0]` it would affect `a[1]` so on and so forth. Is there similar mechanism in vector?

```
vector<int> a(5, 0);
?
```

Comment: Maybe use an `std::vector<int>::iterator`?

Comment: In  your example, `p` is not an array, so there is not "an array within another array". Hmm... do you mean an alias that can be used as if it was a sub-array? For the vector case, would the "sub-vector" be allowed to insert elements?

Comment: "_you can define an array within another array, for example_" - Yes you can, but that's not what you are doing.

Comment: This is just pointer magic and not "defining an array in an array". It is very error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example

```
int a[5];
int *p = &a[1];
```

does not define an array within another array, it only creates a pointer to an element inside the exisiting array. For standard containers like `std::vector` the same can be  achieved by using iterators:

```
vector<int> a(5, 0);           // a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
auto iterator = a.begin() + 1; // "points" to a[1]
*iterator = 2;                 // a = [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Iterators are widely used in the standard library and the go-to-solution to provide access to (sub-)ranges of containers.

---

If you can use C++20 or later you might want to look at [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) instead.

Comment: I just tried, and `operator[]` works on iterators too.

Comment: Yes, you may be right. I looked up the documentation for `std::iterator` and I didn't find `operator[]` anywhere.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 No, you were right, `std::vector` iterators must have `[]`. `std::iterator` is just an obsolete helper class for writing your own iterators, it's unrelated to iterators of the standard containers. But not all *categories* of iterators have `[]`;  [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) you can see that iterators of `std::vector` are required to be "random-access", and random-access ones [must have](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) `[]`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ah, ok. I hadn't realized `std::iterator` was an unrelated class.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Very interesting, I didn't even know where to look this up, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The exact same code `int *p = &a[1];` works if `a` is a vector too.

But it's really not recommended. it's even worse than with the array because a vector can reallocate, and your pointer will be invalidated.

Comment: I think it is better to suggest exactly "update that pointer every single time when anything is added to the vector, otherwise, consider it invalidated".